# Padding between some of the grid spaces and and none between others matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I have made a plot with grid arranged in 2 rows and 5 columns. I need to provide some spacing between the 3 heat maps so that the color bars don't overlap with the adjacent plots but at the same time I need 0 spacing between grid 1(tree),2(genome diagram) and 3(1st heat map).

```
heatmapGS = gridspec.GridSpec(2,5,wspace=0.0,hspace=0.0,width_ratios=[0.60,0.90,1,1,1],height_ratios=[1,1,1,1,1])
```

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Looking at the full scale image, one sees that the 3 identical colorbars have different scales... I don't know if this arrangement is peculiar of your field, but if one wants to compare the heat maps this is misleading... I'd like  to use a 6x2 grid, with the three heatmaps drawn with the same normalisation, close to each other _and without colorbars_ with a single colorbar, _by which you interpret all the heat maps_, drawn in cell (1,6). PS: what a beautiful plot!

Comment: Errata Corrige: «I'd like to use a 2x6 grid»

Comment: No I intend to keep it as separate colour bars, I need to provide padding only between the heat maps, any suggestions?